# Document.write очищает всю страницу

Tags: javascript

Как заменить:

```
    document.write('<img src="' + window.Pic + 'Nickelback.jpg" height="311" width="400">');
```

Так, чтобы страница не стиралсь?

Comment: Пытался так:

        document.getElementById('pole').innerHTML = '<img src="' + window.Pic + 'Nickelback.jpg" height="311" width="400">';

Но хром выдает ошибку: (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null)



Comment: Размещайте скрипт в конце документа. В вашем случае javascript не может найти элемент, так как он еще не создан.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Все варианты верные: и appendChild, и innerHTML, и insertBefore, но есть одно НО... Браузер интерпретирует код сверху вниз. Когда он доходит до вашего javascript-кода, требуемого элемента *ещё не существует*. Попробуйте сделать так:

```
window.onload = function(){//Эта функция выполнится тогда, когда документ полностью загрузится
    var img = document.createElement('img'); 
    img.src = window.Pic + 'Nickelback.jpg'; 
    img.height = 311; img.width = 400; 
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: какого элемента не существует? document.body точно есть.

Answer (score 0):

document.write всегда очищает страницу. это его нормальное поведение. используйте манипуляции с [dom-деревом](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/dom). забегая наперед, скажу, что у dom-элементов есть свойство innerHTML, которое может быть вам полезно.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.appendChild('<img src="' + window.Pic + 'Nickelback.jpg" height="311" width="400">')
```

Comment: хм, мне кажется вы заблуждаетесь. chrome со мной согласен:

> NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.

javascript это не jquery. для того что вы хотели показать, сначала надо создать элемент, а потом использовать innerHTML или outerHTML.

Comment: var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = window.Pic + 'Nickelback.jpg;
img.height = 311;
img.width = 400;
document.body.appendChild(img);

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('element').appendChild(/* ваш элемент */)
```

также почитайте про [insertBefore](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp), [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp), [insertAdjacentHTML](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-insertadjacenthtml/)