# Пустая страница после document.write

Tags: javascript

Использую `document.write`, чтобы дописать html в страницу по нажатию на кнопку, но все существующие элементы куда-то исчезают. Почему, и что делать?

```js
function useDocumentWrite(aText) {
  document.write("<p>" + aText + "</p>");
}

useDocumentWrite("when page is loading");
```

```html
<button onclick="useDocumentWrite('after page loaded')">Use document.write</button>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Document.write очищает всю страницу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/327811/document-write-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83)

Comment: @Darth, по-моему, лучше в другую сторону закрывать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не вызывайте `document.write` после загрузки страницы.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

> *Note:* as `document.write` writes to the document stream, calling
>   `document.write` on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls
>   `document.open`, which will clear the document.
>
> *Заметьте:* так как `document.write` пишет в поток (stream)
>   документа, вызов `document.write` закрытого (загруженного)
>   документа автоматически вызывает `document.open`, что очищает
>   документ.

Можно использовать, например, `document.createElement` или писать в DOM элемент, существующий в документе с самого начала.

```js
function useCreateElement(aText) {
  var newP = document.createElement("p");
  newP.innerText = aText;
  document.body.appendChild(newP);
}

useCreateElement("when page is loading");
```

```html
<button onclick="useCreateElement('after page loaded')">Use document.createElement</button>
```