# Преобразовать массив строк (из prompt) в массив чисел

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Только начинаю учить javascript и столкнулась с такой проблемой. Стоит задача: найти максимальное число, введенное пользователем.
Числа запрашиваю через prompt(). Если вводить однозначные числа, то всё работает. Но, мне необходимо, чтобы была возможность ввода любых целых чисел. Для решения этой проблемы я воспользовалась методом .split. 
Но теперь выводится только первое число, я так понимаю, из-за того, что цифры становятся строковыми значениями и поэтому не могут сравниться. 
Как их можно преобразовать числа? 
Код:

```
    var a = prompt('Введите числа через запятую').split(',');
    var max = a[0];

    for(i = a; i < a; i++){
        if (a[i] > max) {max = a[i]}
    }
    document.write('Максимальное число, которое вы ввели: ' + max);
```

Comment: Про длину массива в цикле забыли https://learn.javascript.ru/array#%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Оставьте этот document.write() уже в покое. Он полезен исключительно в редких случаях!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653289

Answer (score 2):

Для начала вы допустили две ошибки в условии цикла -

```
for(i = a; i < a; i++){
```

`a` это массив, `([] < []) === false`, поэтому у вас тело цикла выполняется только один раз.

### Есть ряд способов превратить строку в число в javascript.

- Самый короткий - [унарный плюс](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81):

```js
var a = ('-13, 23423, .23423, 14.88, 22e8, 3*5,не число,,0x34').split(',');
var max = +a[0];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    a[i] = +a[i];
    if(a[i] > max){max = a[i]}
}
document.write('Максимальное число, которое вы ввели: ' + max);
```

```js
let numbers = ('-13, 23423, .23423, 14.88, 22e8, 3*5,не число,,0x34').split(',');
console.log(numbers.map(string => +string));
```

- Встроенные функции [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) и [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```js
let numbers = ('-13, 23423, .23423, 14.88, 22e8, 3*5,не число,,0x34').split(',');
console.log(numbers.map(string => parseInt(string)));
```

```js
let numbers = ('-13, 23423, .23423, 14.88, 22e8, 3*5,не число,,34').split(',');
console.log(numbers.map(string => parseFloat(string)));
```

- Приведение к нужному типу  помощью какого-нибудь выражения:

```js
let numbers = ('-13,23423,.23423,14.88,22e8,3*5,534,2,2445,45645,не число,,0x34').split(',');
console.log(numbers.map(string => string*1));
console.log(numbers.map(string => string/1));
console.log(numbers.map(string => string**1));
console.log(numbers.map(string => string%++string));// за такое бьют
console.log(numbers.map(string => string-0));
// одно исключение - число и строка складываются как строки
console.log(numbers.map(string => string+0));
```

- Конструктор Number:

```js
let numbers = ('-13,23423,.23423,14.88,22e8,3*5,534,2,2445,45645,не число,,0x34').split(',');
console.log(numbers.map(string => (new Number(string))));
// Здесь вы увидите в консоли объекты
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Да, я потом заметила ошибки и сделала следующим образом:     var a = prompt('Введите числа через запятую ","').split(',');
  var max = +a[0]; 


   for(i = 0; i < +a.length; i++){
    if (+a[i] > max) {max = +a[i]}
   }
   document.write('Максимальное число, которое вы ввели: ' + max);

Answer (score 0):

```js
let justDoIt = true,
    number   = null,
    nums     = [];

do{
  let num = prompt("Введите число:");
  
  if(num === null || num.trim() === ''){ // null - отмена ввода и пустая строка приводят к выходу из цикла
    justDoIt = false;
  }else if((num = parseFloat(num)) && !isNaN(num)){ // parseFloat приводит к числу строку (в данном случае лучше, чем parseInt, ибо может распарсить и дробное число)
    if(number === null || num > number) number = num; // Если ещё нет максимального числа или новое больше - пишем его
    
    nums.push(num); // Для наглядности: сохраняем введённые числа
  }
}while(justDoIt);

if(nums.length > 0){
  console.info(`Вы ввели ряд чисел: ${nums.join(', ')}`);
  console.info(`Самое большое число, введённое Вами: ${number}`);
}else{
  console.info('Вы не ввели чисел!');
}
```