# javascript (callback) необходима помощь

Tags: javascript, callback

Помогите разобраться, где я допустил ошибку или может быть вообще все неправильно написал. 
Нужно чтобы получилась такая последовательность:

1. animateOne появляется сразу
2. animateTwo появляется после animateOne с задержкой 2с
3. massAnimate2 появляется после massAnimate2 с задержкой 2с
4. animateFour появлялся после animateThree с задержкой 2c

   ```
   var massAnimate1 = function(cb) {
     function animateOne (callback) {
       document.write("First animation" + "</br>");
       return callback;
     }
     function animateTwo() {
       setTimeout(function () {
         document.write("Second animation" + "</br>");
       }, 2000);
     }
     animateOne(animateTwo());
     return cb;
   };


   var massAnimate2 = function(val) {
     setTimeout(function(cb){
       function animateThree (callback) {
         document.write("Three animation" + "</br>");
         return callback;
       }
       function animateFour () {
         setTimeout(function () {
           document.write("Four animation"+ "</br>");
         }, 1400);
       }
       animateThree(animateFour());
       return cb;
     }, 2000);
     return val;
   };
   massAnimate1(massAnimate2());
   ```

Пример: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcfmenjd/1/)

Comment: Пропущены скобочки в `return callback()` и `return cb()`

Comment: Упрастите код , опишите все функции в одном объекте, используйте промисы. Вы через неделю в этих "спагетти" уже не разберетесь :)

Answer (score 2):

`massAnimate2` возвращает свой аргумент `val`. Вызов `massAnimate2` в `massAnimate1(massAnimate2());` сделан без параметров, так что внутри `massAnimate2` значение `val` - `undefined`. Таким образом, `massAnimate1` вызывается с параметром `undefined`.

Но это не страшно :), так как внутри `massAnimate1` аргумент `cb` нигде не используется, а только возвращается, а возвращаемое из `massAnimate1` значение игнорируется.

Идем дальше...

Ситуация с `massAnimate1(massAnimate2());` фрактально повторяется внутри `massAnimate1` - `animateOne(animateTwo());` (только `animateTwo` вообще ничего не возвращает).

В общем, весь код какой-то бессмысленный. А по поводу `document.write`: [Пустая страница после document.write](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653289)