# Ajax формирование ссылки

Tags: javascript, ajax

Доброго времени суток! На Ajax'e делаю запрос, в ответ получаю два параметра. Из них пытаюсь сформировать ссылку для воспроизведения аудио файла:

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://portal.com/script.php",
  data: {'rid' : rid,
        'md2' : md2,
        },
  success: function(data) {

document.write('<audio src="portal.com/audio/', data.albom  ,'/track/', data.filename ,'"></audio>');
 } 
});
```

PHP отвечает:

`$response->getBody()->write($filename, $albom);`

Как вывести уже полученный значения, чтобы ссылка получилась вроде:

```
 <audio src="portal.com/audio/meteora/track/fire.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: заменить запятые на плюсы пробовал ?

Comment: да и так все должно работать, оно же последовательно будет вставлять все это, в итоге все сформируется в нужную строку. Вообще не понимаю в чем проблема.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, проблема в document.write скорее всего :)

Comment: Не используй document.write тут, используй [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), или [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) или [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653289/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-document-write

Comment: Утром попробую и отпишусь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер:

```
$arr = array('albom' => $albom, 'filename' => $filename);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Клиент:

```
  ...
  success: function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $("<audio></audio>").
     attr("src", "portal.com/audio/" + data.albom + "/track/" + data.filename).
     appendTo("body");
  }
});
```

Comment: От сервера в консоли, получаю: {"albom":"meteora","filename":"fire.mp3"}, но после обработки Ajax'ом:       success: function(data) {
      console.log('ОТВЕТ: ', data);
    $("<audio></audio>").
     attr("src", "http://portal.com/audio/" + data.albom+ "/track/" + data.filename).
     appendTo("body");
  }  Формируется ссылка: portal.com/audio/undefined/track/undefined

Comment: В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: как "точка с запятой" попала в выражение для `src`?

Comment: У меня в коде нет точки с запятой.

Comment: Сюда почему-то вставилась

Comment: добавьте `consle.log(data.albom);` и `consle.log(data.filename);`

Comment: Если вместо data.albom вывести просто data, ссылка выходит такая: portal.com/audio/{"albom":"meteora","filename":"fire.mp3"}/track/undefined  Выходит, что конкретное поле albom корректно не извлекается

Comment: добавьте `console.log(data.albom);` и `console.log(data.filename);`

Comment: Добавил. В консоли на эти поля выходит ошибка: Uncaught ReferenceError: consle is not defined

Comment: букву "o" добавьте

Comment: Извиняюсь, не понял

Comment: Добавил. Выводит вместо записи undefined

Comment: хм, строка приходит в `data`? Вставьте в начале `success`: `data = JSON.parse(data);`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64896/discussion-between---and-igor).

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов window.open