# php ajax js Помогите вывести данные

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

У меня есть таблица, которую надо выводить данными на ajax.
Но не пойму как вывести эти данные.

```js
function getTableKredit() {
  var id;
  $.ajax({
    url: "credit-table.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      data.forEach(function(item) {
        document.write("<tr><td style='text-align: left'>" + item.description + "</td><td>" + item.grn + "</td><td>" + item.pln + "</td><td>" + item.eur + "</td><td>" + item.usd + "</td><td><a href='?kredit=1&id=" + item.id + "' class='delete-kredit'>Видалити кредит</a></td></tr>");
      })
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <tr class="info">
    <th>Опис</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">ГРН</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">PLN</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">EUR</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">USD</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Завешення кредитів</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- вивести тут -->

  <!-- вивести тут -->
</table>
```

Comment: дайте пример данных, которые аякс будет возвращать

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych да вроде ж ясно все. Единственно что надо сделать, это `document.write` заменить надо на а-ля `$('table').append($('<tr>....</tr>'))`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653289/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-document-write