# Как вывести данные JSON в атрибут data-*

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html5

Есть загнанные в локальное хранилище данные (таблица):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#but2').click(function() {
    var jsonArr = [];
    var obj = {};
    var thNum = document.getElementsByTagName('th').length;
    var arrLength = document.getElementsByTagName('td').length;
    for (i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
      if (i % thNum === 0) {
        obj = {};
      }
      var head = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[i % thNum].innerHTML;
      var content = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML;
      obj[head] = content;
      if (i % thNum === 0) {
        jsonArr.push(obj);
      }
    }
    document.write("<br>" + JSON.stringify(jsonArr));
    localStorage.setItem('myStorage', JSON.stringify(jsonArr));
  });
});
```

Нужно вывести данные из хранилища в атрибут data-name:

```
<button class="good-item__btn-add btn btn-info btn-sm js-add-to-cart"
    data-id="11"
    data-name="сюда вывести данные"
    data-price="1500">
    Добавить в корзину
</button>
```

Желательно вывести не в виде массива, а строковым образом
Возможно ли это, подскажите куда копать???

Comment: `$(selector).attr('data-name', [ваши данные])`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653289/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-document-write

Comment: "вывести не в виде массива, а строковым образом" - что это значит? Вы умеете вывести *не* строковым образом?