# Ошибка в програме

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    document.write(a + "+" + b + "=" + "...")
    var c = a + b
  </script>
  <p id=e></p>
  <button onclick="check()">check</button>
  <input type="text" value="" id="check">
  <script>
    var i = 0
    var z = 0
    document.write("Correct answers:" + i)
    document.write("Wrong answers:" + z)

    function check() {
      var d = document.getElementById("check").value
      if (d == c) {
        var q = document.getElementById("e").style.color = "green"
        q = document.getElementById("e").innerHTML = "Correct"
        i = i + 1
        document.write("Correct answers:" + i)
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        document.write(a + "+" + b + "=" + "...")
        c = a + b

      } else {
        var f = document.getElementById("e").style.color = "red"
        var f = document.getElementById("e").innerHTML = "Wrong"
        z = z + 1
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        document.write(a + "+" + b + "=" + "...")
        c = a + b
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

При правильном ответе должна появляться зеленая надпись 'correct' при неправильной красная 'wrong', также должен бить сщетчик правильних и неправильних ответов, после ответа (без разници какого, правильного или нет) числа в примере должни измениться

Comment: Удалите строчку `document.write(d)`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653289/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-document-write

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо помогло

Comment: `var d=document.getElementById("check").value`

Comment: Вы прочитали вопрос/ответ по ссылке, которую я Вам дал? Перестаньте использовать `document.write`.

Comment: @Igor да, я не знаю как сделать чтоби текст Wrong answers: 0 заменялся на Wrong answers: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> я не знаю как сделать чтоби текст Wrong answers: 0 заменялся на Wrong
>   answers: 1

```html
Expression: <span id="expression">0</span>
<br/><br/> Wrong answers: <span id="countWrong">0</span>
<br/> Right answers: <span id="countRight">0</span>
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="answer" /><button onclick="check()">Check</button>

<script>
  var countWrong = 0;
  var countRight = 0;
  var result;

  function updateExpression() {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    result = a + b;
    document.getElementById("expression").textContent = a + " + " + b + " = ...";
  }
  updateExpression();

  function check() {
    if (document.getElementById("answer").value == result) {
      document.getElementById("countRight").textContent = ++countRight;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("countWrong").textContent = ++countWrong;
    }

    updateExpression();
  }
</script>
```