# Как присвоить значение переменной текста в textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

Я сделал `textarea` через HTML. После в JS хочу переменной `i` присвоить значение текста в `textarea`. Как это реализовать? Так не получаеться.

```js
function print() {
  var i = textarea;
  document.write(i);
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="button" name="submit" onclick="print()" value="Отправить">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function print() {
  var i = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML = i + "<br/>" + output.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<textarea>AAA</textarea>
<input type="button" name="submit" onclick="print()" value="Отправить">
<div id="output"></div>
```

---

Про `document.write`:

[Пустая страница после document.write](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653289/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-document-write)

Comment: <html>
<head>
 <title>Marmid</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function print(){
  var i = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
  document.write(i);
 }
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="button" name="submit" onclick="print()" value="Отправить">
 </body>
</html> вот что получилось но textarea после кнопки удаляеться как сделать так что бы оно оставалось?

Comment: @МаркоСелфи Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе и попробуйте.

Comment: Да но вот в чём проблема оно у вас заменяет текст. А мне надо что бы писало. Тоесть я напишу ААА и нажму на кнопку оно напишет "ААА". А после если напишу привет. Оно сверху ААА должно написать привет. И что бы это все сохранялось при перезагрузке страницы.

Comment: @МаркоСелфи Эти вещи надо писать в тексте вопроса. Про сохранение - задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Так как textarea не имеет атрибута id, используем querySelector вместо getElementById.

```
 var i = document.querySelector("textarea").value
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
<textarea class="alert alert-info" name="text" onclick="addValue()">
</textarea>
<input id="textArea1" th:value="${announce.getText()}" th:hidden="true">
<script>
    function addValue() {
        var val = $("#textArea1").val();
        document.querySelector("textArea").value = val
    }
</script>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]