# нужна помощь с классами JS

Tags: javascript

В классе person есть поля: name, surname , childrencount. Есть метод salary(), который рассчитывает доход человека след. образом.: childrencount*50000, метод print() выводит на экран имя, фамилию, количество детей и доход.
   Из класса person нужно создать массив в котором есть 10 элементов и вывести:

1. Сколько в массиве человек у которых >=5 детей
2. Вывести на экран информацию о людях у которых доход больше 120000

это код которым я пытался реализовать задачу:

```js
class Person{
    constructor(a,b,c){
        this.name = a
        this.surname = b
        this.childrenCount = c
    }
    print(){
        document.write(`<b>Name:</b> ${this.name}<br><b>Surname:</b> ${this.surname}<br><b>Children Count:</b>${this.childrenCount}<br><b>Salary:</b> ${this.salary()}`)
    }
    salary(){
        return this.childrenCount*50000
    }
}

let per = new Person('Vahan', 'Muradyan', 20)
per.print()
```

каким образом можно создать массив из класса?

Comment: не вижу массив - "Из класса person нужно создать массив"

Comment: У вас логическая ошибка, сейчас видно что человек что-то печатает, а у вас на экран вместо этого выводится, скорей всего у класса Person не должно быть метода print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let people = [
  new Person('Vahan', 'Muradyan', 20),
  new Person('John', 'Smith', 2),
  new Person('Jane', 'Doe', 1)
];

people.forEach(item => if (item.salary() > 120000) { item.print(); });
```

---

[Пустая страница после document.write](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653289/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-document-write)

Comment: спасибо, сработало но при помощи map() "let people = [
  new Person('Vahan', 'Muradyan', 20),
  new Person('John', 'Smith', 2),
  new Person('Jane', 'Doe', 1)
];
people.push(new Person('Edgar', 'Grigoryan', 10))
people.map(item => {if(item.salary() > 120000){
    item.print(); 
}});"