# (JS) при обрабатывании onclick функция переданная в onclick() выполняется не полностью

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="1" style="display: flex; align-items: center;justify-content: center"><img  id="myImageId"  src="https://instagram.fiev21-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/159546124_832196654032144_1197400507279358836_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=instagram.fiev21-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=YPevkqp0-r0AX_OslIW&edm=AP_V10EAAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=9d816417fc881bf6b2d42670bf2a10d0&oe=609EF5FA&_nc_sid=4f375e" style="display: none; width: 500px; height: 600px"></div>
<div id="2" style="display:flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column"><img  id="myImageId2" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShdhYh-uu6c_64ixZ9o-mxFYOEybp2lvwBhA&usqp=CAU"  style="display: none">
    <input type="button" style="display: none" id="but_1" value="Нажми шоб вийти" onclick="davayPoNovoy()">
</div>


<script>




function davayPoNovoy () {
    innerTime:  while (true) {
        let userName = prompt("Це Вова?", '');

        if (userName == 'Ваван') {

            let pass = prompt('Пароль?', '');

            if (pass == 'Хоттабич') {
                alert('Дратуті!');

                let img = document.getElementById('myImageId');

                img.style.display = '';
                document.write(img.style.display);

                break innerTime;
            }


            while (true) {

                if (pass == '' || pass == null) continue innerTime;


                else {
                    alert('Неверный пароль');
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else if (userName == '' || userName == null) {
            alert('Отменено');
        } else {
            alert("Я вас не знаю");

            let img2 = document.getElementById('myImageId2');
            let but = document.getElementById('but_1');

            img2.style.display = '';
            but.style.display = '';
            document.write(img2.style.display, but.style.display);


            break;
        }
    }

}

davayPoNovoy();
```

Здравствуйте, проблема такая: если ввести юзернейм не "Ваван", то соответственно исполняется вторая ветка if, после которой вы получаете вывод картинки и кнопку "Нажми чтобы выйти" после нажатия на кнопку, в кнопку передается та же функция, что выводиться на самом начале работы программы,  и по идеи вы бы должны при повторном вводе юзернейм  не "Ваван" получить опять картинку и кнопку и такой себе "цикл", но функция заканчивается на выводе alert`ов  во всех случаях, и картинки с кнопкой не выводяться.

```
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653289/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-document-write

Comment: Спасибо, огромное! Вы мне очень помогли, как тут отметить Ваш комент как решение вопроса?

Comment: Когда у Вас будет достаточно репутации (15?), Вы сможете проголосовать за тот ответ (а при желании - и за вопрос). Это я их написал. :)