# Не срабатывает выборка getDocumentById в JavaScript. Соединение html страницы и js страницы я проверил. id запроса и элемента совпадают. Код проверил

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: js code]

**html код**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS textbook</title>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="textbooksScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="time">Hello</h1>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**JS код**

```
document.write('Hello world!');

var elem = document.getElementById('time');

alert(elem.innerHTML);
```

**Консоль выдает ошибку**

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')
at textbooksScript.js:25

**Схема папки и консоль на фото**

Comment: закомментируй строчку `document.write('Hello world!');`

Comment: ну и если код находится в textbooksScript.js - то в момент вызова getElementById элемента еще нет на странице - поэтому ничего и не находится

Comment: Код JS добавлен в <head> браузер сначала читает его. А код  html ниже на странице, и браузер от туда выбирает Id. До этого все срабатывало. Что могло произойти c getElementById, если js проверяет все id на странице и первый выбирает.

Comment: _js проверяет все id на странице и первый выбирает._ - так как этот код расположен в head, выполняется он **ДО** того, как "на странице" появится разметка после `head`, поэтому никакого элемента и не будет найдено

Comment: Понял тебя! Благодарю!

Comment: А как тогда сделать, чтобы он исполнялся в нужный момент?

Comment: либо поместить скрипт после создания элемента, либо в скрипте проводить действия после отгрузки страницы целиком, например, определив `window.onload`

Comment: Благодарю! Изучу window.onload.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно или подключение скрипта перенести в подвал сайта после тега body или добавить обертку к вашему скрипту, которая будет говорить, что запускать скрипт надо после загрузки DOM. Есть еще вариант с [async/defer](https://learn.javascript.ru/script-async-defer)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' , ()=>{


  var elem = document.getElementById('time');

  alert(elem.innerHTML);

})
```

Comment: `document.write('Hello world!');` - ?? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653289/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-document-write

Comment: спасибо, исправил. Никогда не пользовался этим, код скопировал из вопроса